# When should I use Entity SQL and LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, wcf

When should I use Entity SQL and LINQ ?

I have an exercice with Entity Framework (with models designer). I have 5 models : Work, Employee, ... In the solution, they use the query in the picture to query an entity (It's Entity SQL). Why isn't it simply LINQ ? Why the answer is not the "C" ? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what SQL your Entity Framework Linq queries generate, simply run your program in debug mode, make a breakpoint and inspect the `IQueryable<T>` object of your choice, e.g.

```
var es = database.ExternalOrderEntities.Where(e => e.OrderNum == someOrderNum);
```

It will serialize to a SQL string. Regarding your multiple-choice question, it does not make sense to me the way you describe it.